# WebViewPool, Last html page show before new url when reuse WebView from WebViewPool

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

There is a **WebViewPool**,when Activity/Fragment is destoryed,webview will be reset and add to the WebViewPool.

The following is the code of WebViewPool:

```java
public class WebViewPool {

  private static volatile WebViewPool sINSTANCE;
  private int mMaxSize;

  private List<WebView> mAvailableList;
  private List<WebView> mInUsedList;
  private IWebViewPoolFactory mFactory;

  private WebViewPool() {

  }

  public static WebViewPool getInstance() {
    if (sINSTANCE == null) {
      synchronized (WebViewPool.class) {
        if (sINSTANCE == null) {
          sINSTANCE = new WebViewPool();
        }
      }
    }
    return sINSTANCE;
  }

  public void init(IWebViewPoolFactory factory,boolean lazy) {
    init(2, factory,lazy);
  }

  public void init(int maxSize, IWebViewPoolFactory factory,boolean lazy) {
    mMaxSize = maxSize;
    mFactory = factory;
    mAvailableList = new ArrayList<>(maxSize);
    mInUsedList = new ArrayList<>(maxSize);
    if (!lazy) {
      create();
    }
  }


  private synchronized void create() {
    if (mFactory == null) {
      return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mMaxSize; i++) {
      WebView webView = mFactory.create(new MutableContextWrapper(APP.getApplicationContext()));
      mAvailableList.add(webView);
    }
  }

  /**
   * get webview form pool
   * @param context
   * @return
   */
  public synchronized WebView getWebView(Context context) {
    if(!(context instanceof Activity)){
      throw new IllegalStateException("Context must be Activity");
    }
    WebView webView = null;
    if (mAvailableList.size() > 0) {
      webView = mAvailableList.remove(0);

    } else {
      if (mFactory != null) {
        webView = mFactory.create(new MutableContextWrapper(APP.getApplicationContext()));
      }
    }
    if (webView != null) {
      ((MutableContextWrapper) webView.getContext()).setBaseContext(context);
      mInUsedList.add(webView);
    }
    return webView;
  }

  /**
   * reset/destroy webview when activity/fragemnt is destroyed
   * @param webView
   */
  public synchronized void restWebView(WebView webView) {
    if (webView == null || mFactory == null) {
      return;
    }
    mFactory.reset(webView);
    ((MutableContextWrapper) webView.getContext()).setBaseContext(APP.getApplicationContext());
    if (mInUsedList.contains(webView)) {
      mInUsedList.remove(webView);
      if (mAvailableList.size() < mMaxSize) {
        mAvailableList.add(webView);
      } else {
        mFactory.destroy(webView);
      }
    } else {
      mFactory.destroy(webView);
    }
  }
}
```

the following is some code of `reset` function:

```java
    public void reset(WebView webView) {
        if(webView==null){
            return;
        }
        ViewParent viewParent = webView.getParent();
        if (viewParent!=null) {
            ((ViewGroup)viewParent).removeView(webView);
        }
        webView.stopLoading();
        webView.clearCache(false);
        webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView.clearHistory();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

But when reuse the webview,last html page show first before new url sometimes.It doesn't happened everytime. I searched in Google, but not work.Does anyone know the reason? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved finally! The reason is that add the reseted WebView to available list while `about:blank` is not loaded so that `clearHistory()` doesn't work.

So, reset the webview but do not add to available list when activity/fragment is destroyed, call `clearHistory()` at `onPageFinished()` when url is `about:blank`:

```java
@Override
public void onPageFinish(String url, boolean success) {
    if("about:blank".equals(url)){
        webView.clearHistory();
        //then add the webview to available list;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Clearing the history in `onPageFinished()` of `loadUrl("about:blank")` did not work as expected.

It should clear the whole history including the `"about:blank"` load, which it wasn't.

So I tried to clear the history in `onPageFinished()` of the first-ever URL load. Which clears the previous history.

```
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
    if (pageFinishedCounter == 0) {
    // This is required to clear history, so that previous loaded page is not visible on back press.
        view.clearHistory()
    }
}
```

Now, it works as expected.

Comment: Could you post the code about `pageFinishedCounter`?